# Can I have both Language and Country path prefixes?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

On our site, paths are all prefixed by language and country. For example:

http://example.com/en/us/about

In Drupal 7, a previous vendor implemented this by using the [Persistent URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/purl) module, which rewrites all on-page URLs to include the prefix of your choice. PURL was used to add add the country as a prefix to each path. However, it fails when URL Prefix language negotiation is turned on, requiring a core hack to locale.inc to make both work together to avoid the language negotiation from stomping over our prefix:

```
@@ -462,7 +462,7@@ -462,7 +462,7 @@ function locale_language_url_rewrite_url(&$path, &$options) {

       case LOCALE_LANGUAGE_NEGOTIATION_URL_PREFIX:
         if (!empty($options['language']->prefix)) {
-          $options['prefix'] = $options['language']->prefix . '/';
+          $options['prefix'] = $options['language']->prefix . '/' . $options['prefix'];
         }
         break;
     }
```

We are rebuilding the site in Drupal 8, and this is one of the things we need to figure out. Obviously, we'd like to avoid having to reinstate some kind of core hack, but by the same token, we can't change the URL structure due to client requirements.

Is there any way we can pass and preserve both language and country information via path prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

you can either use [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) patterns or [pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) which is still -dev .. to adapt your paths.